# Sheets Merge Multiple Rows into 1 Row

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, trim, google-query-language

I have multiple rows, each containing cells that do not overlap and I want to easily merge them into a single row with a formula. Bonus if I can also fill in the empty cells with something. In this case the text "off". All in a single formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9)))
```

and:

```
=INDEX(IF(TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9))=""; "off"; TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9)))
```

Comment: Question. If I do have overlap I will get "on on" in the resulting cell. I know the original question showed no overlap. Is there a simple adjustment for the value to just be unique? Instead of "on on" just "on".

Comment: @kenitech try: `=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IF(TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9))=""; "off"; TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9)), "on on", "on"))`

Comment: That'll do it! Just missing one ")" after the second TRIM. The following works: 
 =INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IF(TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9))="", "off", TRIM(QUERY(B2:H7;;9^9)))  ,"on on", "on"))